# The message after applying for a job is too bright

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, dark-mode

After applying for a job with easy apply button, you get a success message.
In that message, you have the ability to change your Job Search Status.
However, the contrast/colors are kind of too bright to a point where you can't read them without selecting the text or squeezing your eyes and come closer to the screen.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Too bright]

Note that I am using Chrome, Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit), with dark mode on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  This modal has been updated to support dark mode now.

[image: dark mode modal]