# Message after applying for a job is still too bright

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, dark-mode

*[The message after applying for a job is too bright](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399405/5099208)*

It is basically a duplicate of the question above. The popup survey is still too bright in *dark mode*.

I am using dark mode on [macOS v10.15.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) and Firefox 79.0.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We've pushed some tweaks and this should now be resolved. Let me know if you're still seeing this issue.